# django-filter messing around with empty field

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I setup [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/) to filter some of my listings. Here is one of them, with a custom form:

```
class BookingListFiltersForm(forms.Form):

    state__in = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=Booking.STATE_CHOICES, required=False,
        label=_("État"), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    source__in = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Platform.objects.all(), required=False,
        label=_("Source"), widget=ModelSelect2Multiple(
            url='autocomplete:platform'))


class BookingManagerFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    payments__date = filters.DateFilter(method='payments__date_filter')
    payments__method = filters.ChoiceFilter(
        method='payments__method_filter',
        choices=BookingPayment.METHOD_CHOICES,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = {
            'period': [
                'endswith', 'endswith__gte', 'endswith__lte',
                'startswith', 'startswith__gte', 'startswith__lte',
            ],
            'state': ['in'],
            'source': ['in'],
            'booking_date': ['date', 'date__lte', 'date__gte'],
            'accommodation': ['in'],
            'guest': ['exact']
        }

    def get_form_class(self):
        return BookingListFiltersForm

    def payments__date_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(**{name: value})

    def payments__method_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(**{name: value})
```

The form is submitted by GET method. When the field "source__in" is empty, the querystring looks like this "?state__in=1". In such case, I have no result in my page (which is unexpected, if a field is not filled in, I would expect that the results are not filtered upon this field).

I looked at debug toolbar to have more information about the executed SQL query. Surprisingly, I found no SQL query for the related queryset! (while if querystring is "?state__in=1&source__in=2" for instance, the result is as expected, and I can find related queries in debug toolbar)

So I tried to force the impression of the SQL query using `print(str(filters.qs.query))`. New surprise, this triggered an `EmptyResultSet` exception:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/tony/Workspace/cocoonr/utils/views/manager.py" in dispatch
  29.         return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get
  142.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

File "/home/tony/Workspace/cocoonr/booking/views/manager.py" in get_queryset
  73.         queryset = super().get_queryset()

File "/home/tony/Workspace/cocoonr/utils/views/common.py" in get_queryset
  118.         print(self.filters.qs.query)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in __str__
  252.         sql, params = self.sql_with_params()

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in sql_with_params
  260.         return self.get_compiler(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).as_sql()

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  461.                 where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  393.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  98.                     raise EmptyResultSet

Exception Type: EmptyResultSet at /manager/booking/bookings/
Exception Value:
```

Now I am stuck, I have no idea what is going wrong and how to debug any further.

I tried to pass the following querystring for the sake of testing: "?state__in=1&source__in=". In such case, the filtering works properly, but the filter form shows an error "« » is not a valid value" for the field "source__in".

In addition, here is the relevant mixin in `utils/views/common.py`:

```
class ListFilterMixin:

    filters_class = None
    default_filters = None

    @cached_property
    def filters(self):
        return self.get_filters()

    def get_filters(self):
        if self.filters_class:
            qstring = self.request.GET
            if not qstring and self.default_filters:
                qstring = QueryDict(self.default_filters)
            return self.filters_class(
                qstring, self.get_unfiltered_queryset(), request=self.request)
        else:
            return None

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.filters.qs.query)  # <--- Line 118
        # ...

    def get_unfiltered_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()
```

And the view class in `booking/views/manager.py`:

```
class BookingListView(ListView):
    """List of all bookings."""

    model = Booking
    default_filters = 'state__in=1'
    filters_class = BookingManagerFilter
    paginate_by = 30
    ordering = '-pk'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()  # <--- Line 73
        # ...
```

Also, so you have the full inheritence tree, note that the `ListView` used above is `utils.views.manager.ListView`:

```
class ListView(BulkActionsMixin, ManagerMixin, BaseListView):
    pass
```

And `BaseListView` is `utils.views.common.ListView`:

```
class ListView(ListFilterMixin, AgencyMixin, ContextMixin, BaseListView):
    pass
```

The last `BaseListView` is `django.views.generic.list.ListView`.

---

Using `ipdb` to debug as suggested by Kamil, I noticed a strange thing that is likely the cause of this behavior:

```
ipdb> next
> /home.tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_filters/filters.py(167)filter()
    166     def filter(self, qs, value):
--> 167         if value != self.null_value:
    168             return super().filter(qs, value)

ipdb> self.null_value
'null'
ipdb> value
<QuerySet []>
ipdb> self.field_name
'source'
ipdb> self.lookup_expr
'in'
ipdb>
```

So the subsequent code, considers `source__in` is not empty and adds `source__in=empty_queryset` to the filters. I guess django then guess that the result cannot evaluate to a non-empty queryset and saves a useless query.

Is it a bug in `django-filters` or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: could you share code from `"/home/tony/Workspace/cocoonr/utils/views/common.py" in get_queryset` and `"/home/tony/Workspace/cocoonr/booking/views/manager.py" in get_queryset`?

Comment: I edited my question to add the information you asked.

Comment: Instead of using `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`, use [`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter-and-modelmultiplechoicefilter-arguments)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I dont understand why. `Filter`s are to be used in a `FilterSet`, not in a `Form`. I tried it anyway but got an `AttributeError` when trying to display the field in the template: `'ModelMultipleChoiceFilter' object has no attribute 'errors'`. Maybe I didn't understand what you meant?

Comment: Could you also add your Booking and Platform models above and the expected result when you don't include the source field?

Comment: @Angela Booking model has 33 fields and is 500 lines long. Can you tell me how this model may help you figuring out the issue so I can show only the relevant part? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Angela I modified my answer to explain the expected behavior: "if a field is not filled in, I would expect that the results are not filtered upon this field"

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I wanted to better understand the options for your source field in your form, however I think I can work it out now. What are the versions of django and django-filter that you are using?

Comment: @Angela it is quite a simple foreign key: `source = models.ForeignKey('broadcast.Platform', models.PROTECT, related_name='bookings', verbose_name=_("source"))`

Comment: Django 2.0.6 and django-filter 2.0.0

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I've updated my answer. Check if it answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

Apparently `django-filters` does not handle correctly the lookup `in` for foreign keys. The default filter for `source__in` for instance, is `ModelChoiceFilter`. So I had to explicitely define it as a `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`.

However I faced another issue which is that `source__in=10&source__in=7` roughly translates into `Q(source__in=10) | Q(source__in=7)`. Which is raises an exception as 10 and 7 are not iterables. So I changed my code to use the `exact` lookup instead of `in` but still use the `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`. Which, in the end, gives the following:

```
class BookingListFiltersForm(forms.Form):

    state__in = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=Booking.STATE_CHOICES, required=False,
        label=_("État"), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    source = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Platform.objects.all(), required=False,
        label=_("Source"), widget=ModelSelect2Multiple(
            url='autocomplete:platform'))


class BookingManagerFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    source = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Platform.objects.all())
    payments__date = filters.DateFilter(method='payments__date_filter')
    payments__method = filters.ChoiceFilter(
        method='payments__method_filter',
        choices=BookingPayment.METHOD_CHOICES,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = {
            'period': [
                'endswith', 'endswith__gte', 'endswith__lte',
                'startswith', 'startswith__gte', 'startswith__lte',
            ],
            'state': ['in'],
            'source': ['exact'],
            'booking_date': ['date', 'date__lte', 'date__gte'],
            'accommodation': ['exact'],
            'guest': ['exact']
        }

    def get_form_class(self):
        return BookingListFiltersForm
```

Answer (score 7):

I think documentation answers your question:

[Filtering by an empty string](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/tips.html#filtering-by-an-empty-string)

> It’s not currently possible to filter by an empty string, since empty
>   values are interpreted as a skipped filter.
>
> ```
> GET http://localhost/api/my-model?myfield=
> ```

Further in the docs you have examples of possible solutions. Im putting here one of them

> **Solution 1: Magic values**
>
> You can override the filter() method of a filter class to specifically
>   check for magic values. This is similar to the ChoiceFilter’s null
>   value handling.
>
> `GET http://localhost/api/my-model?myfield=EMPTY`
>
> ```
> class MyCharFilter(filters.CharFilter):
>     empty_value = 'EMPTY'
>
>     def filter(self, qs, value):
>         if value != self.empty_value:
>             return super(MyCharFilter, self).filter(qs, value)
>
>         qs = self.get_method(qs)(**{'%s__%s' % (self.name, self.lookup_expr): ""})
>         return qs.distinct() if self.distinct else qs
> ```

---

Right now i feel there is not enough information to solve your problem. I left a comment under your question. If you can provide that extra information it would greatly help understand what is going on.

For here are some tips that can help you track this bug:

- Install [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/). it will help you execute code step by step and inspect each variables.
- Drop breakpoint `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` before line

  ```
  File "/home/tony/.venvs/cocoonr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get
    142.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  ```

I suspect you should find the culprit in https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/82a47fb7bbddedf179f110723003f3b28682d7fe/django_filters/filterset.py#L215

You can do something like this

```
class BookingManagerFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    # your previous code here

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        return super(BookingManagerFilter, self)filter_queryset(queryset):
```

And run your endpoint, ipdb will stop the app and you will be able to step into the code and inspect it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use ipdb, I think it allows me to find a clue to help figuring out the issue.

Comment: « It’s not currently possible to filter by an empty string, since empty values are interpreted as a skipped filter. » This is actually the behavior I want to achieve. I want that if the filter to be skipped if the field is not present or blank. As specified in the doc you mentionned, this should be the expected default behavior. But it's not as the query ends up with `source__in=<QuerySet []>`.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I've looked multiple times at code you provided and unfortuantely i cannot spot the problem. I think that you should use `ipdb` to go further up in the call stack and find where that empty queryset is coming from.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard another thing that i would recommend is to temporarily get rid of `cached_property` decorator in `ListFilterMixin.filters` and use just `property` sometimes cached properties can hide the problem.
After you do it check the behavior again and use `ipdb`

Comment: I awarded you the bounty although the answer does not solve my issue, because I had no point not to award it. However I eventually found the issue and answered my own question. I think it can be considered a bug in django-filters but I managed to work it around.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard Thank you. Great that you were able to solve this issue.